# How to enable status list on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I install sharepoint 2010 internet enterprise, I created web application, when I conneted webUrl -- Site action\more option cannot see **status list**

please help me enable Status list

Answer (score 5):

Go to site actions->site features -> Manage site features -> enable "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Features". 
Then you will be able to see the status list template and can create it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only available in the Business Intelligence Center

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint 2010 Central Admin the enterprise features are located at "Upgrade and Migration->Enable Enterprise Features" If they are already enabled go to "Upgrade and Migration->Enable Features on Existing Sites"